# Python urllib to skip URL on HTTP or URL error

Tags: python, lxml, urllib

How can I modify my script to skip a URL if the connection times out or is invalid/404?

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#parser.py: Downloads Bibles and parses all data within <article> tags.

__author__      = "Cody Bouche"
__copyright__   = "Copyright 2012 Digital Bible Society"

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as html
import urlparse
import os, sys
import urllib2
import re

print ("downloading and parsing Bibles...")
root = html.parse(open('links.html'))
for link in root.findall('//a'):
    url = link.get('href')
    name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
    dirname = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('.')[-1]
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    s = f.read()
    if (os.path.isdir(dirname) == 0):
        os.mkdir(dirname)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
    articleTag = soup.html.body.article
    converted = str(articleTag)
    full_path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
    open(full_path, 'wb').write(converted)
    print(name)
print("DOWNLOADS COMPLETE!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the timeout to your request add the `timeout` variable to your call to `urlopen`. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

> The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for
>   blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the
>   global default timeout setting will be used). This actually only works
>   for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP connections.

Refer to this guide's section on [how to handle exceptions with urllib2](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#handling-exceptions). Actually I found the whole guide very useful.

The `request timeout` exception code is `408`. Wrapping it up, if you were to handle timeout exceptions you would:

```
try:
    response = urlopen(req, 3) # 3 seconds
except URLError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        if e.code==408:
            print 'Timeout ', e.code
        if e.code==404:
            print 'File Not Found ', e.code
        # etc etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your urlopen line under a try catch statment. Look this up:

docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html section 8.3

Look at the different exceptions and when you encounter one just restart the loop using the statement continue